# How call a method when a UICollectionViewCell is pressed?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to call another UIViewController when a UICollectionViewCell is pressed, but I just can't. Which one of the following method i should use?

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just link the `UICollectionViewCell` to a new view controller in storyboard!
You don't need those methods.

Comment: If you have AViewController and BViewController you have to import BViewController.h in you AViewController.m in order to make it work. If you did this, the problem is elsewhere, so check carefully the segue.

Comment: It was solved. The segue method must be linked to the UIViewCell on the UICollectionView and then add the method below:

`-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AbrirPerfilSegue"]) {
        
        CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)sender;
        
        PerfilViewController *perfil = (PerfilViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];     
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case you may want to use a storyboard and establish a segue from your cell to another viewcontroller. That would work if you want to link every cell to the same view controller class.
If you need to instantiate view controllers of different classes or if you are not using a storyboard then you will use first function you mentioned

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```